# Getting Margin in DialogFragment by Default?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am creating an app which uses dialog fragement which look like this

[image]

As you can see i am getting a top margin in the dialog fragment which didnt set which you can see from my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/str_add_drop"
    android:textSize="@dimen/tv_title_font_size"/>
<ImageButton
    android:background="@null"
    android:id="@+id/btn_close"
    android:layout_width="12dp"
    android:layout_height="12dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/tv_title"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/tv_title"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_drop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_title"
    android:hint="@string/hint_et_drop"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/bpv_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/et_drop"></DatePicker>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add_it"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/bpv_date"
    android:text="@string/str_add_it"
    android:textAllCaps="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please tell me why i am getting this margin by default and how can i correct this.

Answer (score 2):

styles.xml

```
<style name="FullScreenDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">
        @android:color/transparent
    </item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

ExampleDialogFragment.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.FullScreenDialog);
}
```

That's all, you can use your custom dialog fragment in fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

but before setContentView method in onCreate() method of your custom dialog.

Comment: what is `getWindow()` my program doesn't recognise it

Comment: From where you are accessing dialog..? Fragment or activity..? Try these: getActivity().getWindow().... or getDialog().getWindow()..... or lastly dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: I am accesing from Fragment subclass. i think i cannot use `getWindow()` in fragment context

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to make any changes in your dialog xml file, just set the style for your dialog fragment.
The code below will cover the entire activity with no margins:

res/values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    ...
    <!-- your dialog style -->
    <style name="DialogFragment" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

YourDialogFragment.java

```
public class YourDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private Dialog mDialog;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        mDialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogFragment);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        layoutParams.copyFrom(mDialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
        layoutParams.windowAnimations = R.style.SlideUpDownDialog;

        final View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.dialog_fragment_layout, null);
        mDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
        mDialog.setContentView(view);

        return mDialog;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_layout, container, false);

        mDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        return v;
    }

    ...
}
```